# Видео с камеры в размер окна PyQt5

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, opencv, resizeevent

Просьба помочь с решением вопроса, не получается сделать видео с камеры под размер окна.

Хочется чтобы размер видео подгонялось под размер окна при его уменьшение и увеличение.

```
from ctypes import resize
import cv2
import sys
import numpy as np
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtCore

from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import *
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from MainWindow import Ui_MainWindow


def hhmmss(ms):
    # s = 1000
    # m = 60000
    # h = 360000
    h, r = divmod(ms, 36000)
    m, r = divmod(r, 60000)
    s, _ = divmod(r, 1000)
    return ("%d:%02d:%02d" % (h,m,s)) if h else ("%d:%02d" % (m,s))


class ViewerWindow(QMainWindow):
    state = pyqtSignal(bool)

    def closeEvent(self, e):
        # Выдать состояние окна, чтобы обновить кнопку переключения средства просмотра.
        self.state.emit(False)


class PlaylistModel(QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self, playlist, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PlaylistModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.playlist = playlist

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            media = self.playlist.media(index.row())
            return media.canonicalUrl().fileName()

    def rowCount(self, index):
        return self.playlist.mediaCount()


# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
class ThreadOpenCV(QThread):
    changePixmap = pyqtSignal(QImage)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)  
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 24)
        # cap.set(cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)  # работает или нет? фулл экран
      
   
        
        while True:
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            if ret:
                # video_width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
                # video_height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
                # screen_rect = app.desktop().screenGeometry()
                # video_width = (screen_rect.width() if video_width > screen_rect.width() else video_width)
                # video_height = (screen_rect.height() if video_height > screen_rect.height() else video_height)
                # frame = cv2.resize(frame, (self.widgetForCv2().width(), self.widgetForCv2().height()), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
                # frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                
        
                frame_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                frame_expanded = np.expand_dims(frame_rgb, axis=0)  
                rgbImage = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

                h, w, ch = rgbImage.shape
                bytesPerLine = ch * w
                convertToQtFormat = QImage(
                    rgbImage.data, w, h, bytesPerLine, QImage.Format_RGB888)
                p = convertToQtFormat.scaled(640, 480, Qt.KeepAspectRatio) 
                self.changePixmap.emit(p)
                
                # self.video_size = QtCore.QSize(video_width, video_height)
                if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
                    break
            
            self.msleep(20)                     
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            

class WidgetForCv2(QtWidgets.QMainWindow,):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()  
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.setWindowOpacity(0.6) #Прозрачность
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint) #поверх окон
        
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(640, 480))

       

        self.label_video = QLabel()
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.label_video)

        self.thread = ThreadOpenCV()     #
        self.thread.changePixmap.connect(self.setImage)
        
    def setImage(self, image):
        self.label_video.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(image))
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^         


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.player = QMediaPlayer()

        self.player.error.connect(self.erroralert)
        self.player.play()

        # Настроить плейлист.
        self.playlist = QMediaPlaylist()
        self.player.setPlaylist(self.playlist)

        # Добавить просмотрщик для воспроизведения видео, отдельное плавающее окно
        self.viewer = ViewerWindow(self)
        self.viewer.setWindowFlags(self.viewer.windowFlags() | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.viewer.setMinimumSize(QSize(1920 ,1080))
        # self.viewer.setMinimumSize(QSize(640, 480))        
        self.viewer.setWindowOpacity(0.6)             # прозрачность окна   0.6

        videoWidget = QVideoWidget()
        self.viewer.setCentralWidget(videoWidget)
        self.player.setVideoOutput(videoWidget)

        self.playButton.pressed.connect(self.player.play)
        self.stopButton.pressed.connect(self.player.stop)
      
        self.viewButton.toggled.connect(self.toggle_viewer)
        self.viewer.state.connect(self.viewButton.setChecked)

        self.model = PlaylistModel(self.playlist)
        self.playlistView.setModel(self.model)
        self.playlist.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.playlist_position_changed)
        selection_model = self.playlistView.selectionModel()
        selection_model.selectionChanged.connect(self.playlist_selection_changed)

        self.player.durationChanged.connect(self.update_duration)
        self.player.positionChanged.connect(self.update_position)
        self.timeSlider.valueChanged.connect(self.player.setPosition)

        self.open_file_action.triggered.connect(self.open_file)

        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv         
        self.widgetForCv2 = WidgetForCv2()
        
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^         

    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        if e.mimeData().hasUrls():
            e.acceptProposedAction()

    def dropEvent(self, e):
        for url in e.mimeData().urls():
            self.playlist.addMedia(
                QMediaContent(url)
            )

        self.model.layoutChanged.emit()

        # Если не играет, ищу сначала из недавно добавленных + играть.
        if self.player.state() != QMediaPlayer.PlayingState:
            i = self.playlist.mediaCount() - len(e.mimeData().urls())
            self.playlist.setCurrentIndex(i)
            self.player.play()

    def open_file(self):
        path, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self, 
            "Open file", 
            "", 
# +++
            "mp4 Video (*.mp4);;mp3 Audio (*.mp3);;Movie files (*.mov);;avi Video (*.avi)")

        if path:
            self.playlist.addMedia(
                QMediaContent(
                    QUrl.fromLocalFile(path)
                )
            )

        self.model.layoutChanged.emit()

    def update_duration(self, mc):
        self.timeSlider.setMaximum(self.player.duration())
        duration = self.player.duration()

        if duration >= 0:
            self.totalTimeLabel.setText(hhmmss(duration))

    def update_position(self, *args):
        position = self.player.position()
        if position >= 0:
            self.currentTimeLabel.setText(hhmmss(position))

        # Отключите события, чтобы обновление не вызывало событие setPosition
        self.timeSlider.blockSignals(True)
        self.timeSlider.setValue(position)
        self.timeSlider.blockSignals(False)

    def playlist_selection_changed(self, ix):
        # Мы получаем QItemSelection от selectionChanged.
        i = ix.indexes()[0].row()
        self.playlist.setCurrentIndex(i)

    def playlist_position_changed(self, i):
        if i > -1:
            ix = self.model.index(i)
            self.playlistView.setCurrentIndex(ix)

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv         
    def toggle_viewer(self, state):
        if state:
            if self.player.state():                                        # +++
                self.viewer.show()
            else:                                                          # +++
                self.widgetForCv2.thread.start()                           # +++       
                QTimer.singleShot(300, self.widgetForCv2.show)             # +++              
        else:
            self.viewer.hide()
            self.widgetForCv2.hide()                                       # +++
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^         

    def erroralert(self, *args):
        print(args)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName("Failamp")
    app.setStyle("Fusion")

    palette = QPalette()
    palette.setColor(QPalette.Window, QColor(53, 53, 53))
    palette.setColor(QPalette.WindowText, Qt.white)
    palette.setColor(QPalette.Base, QColor(25, 25, 25))
    palette.setColor(QPalette.AlternateBase, QColor(53, 53, 53))
    palette.setColor(QPalette.ToolTipBase, Qt.white)
    palette.setColor(QPalette.ToolTipText, Qt.white)
    palette.setColor(QPalette.Text, Qt.white)
    palette.setColor(QPalette.Button, QColor(53, 53, 53))
    palette.setColor(QPalette.ButtonText, Qt.white)
    palette.setColor(QPalette.BrightText, Qt.red)
    palette.setColor(QPalette.Link, QColor(42, 130, 218))
    palette.setColor(QPalette.Highlight, QColor(42, 130, 218))
    palette.setColor(QPalette.HighlightedText, Qt.black)
    app.setPalette(palette)
    app.setStyleSheet(
        "QToolTip { color: #ffffff; background-color: #2a82da; border: 1px solid white; }")

    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: Скрин]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
from ctypes import resize
import cv2
import numpy as np

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import *
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import *

#from MainWindow import Ui_MainWindow
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(484, 371)
        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.centralWidget.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.centralWidget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName("centralWidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(11, 11, 11, 11)
        self.horizontalLayout.setSpacing(6)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(6)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.playlistView = QtWidgets.QListView(self.centralWidget)
        self.playlistView.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.playlistView.setProperty("showDropIndicator", True)
        self.playlistView.setDragDropMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.DropOnly)
        self.playlistView.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        self.playlistView.setUniformItemSizes(True)
        self.playlistView.setObjectName("playlistView")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.playlistView)
        self.horizontalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setSpacing(6)
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_4")
        self.currentTimeLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.currentTimeLabel.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(80, 0))
        self.currentTimeLabel.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight|QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.currentTimeLabel.setObjectName("currentTimeLabel")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.currentTimeLabel)
        self.timeSlider = QtWidgets.QSlider(self.centralWidget)
        self.timeSlider.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.timeSlider.setObjectName("timeSlider")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.timeSlider)
        self.totalTimeLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.totalTimeLabel.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(80, 0))
        self.totalTimeLabel.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeading|QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.totalTimeLabel.setObjectName("totalTimeLabel")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.totalTimeLabel)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_4)
        self.horizontalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_5.setSpacing(6)
        self.horizontalLayout_5.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_5")
        self.playButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralWidget)
 
        self.playButton.setText("play")
        icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("images/control.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.playButton.setIcon(icon1)
        self.playButton.setObjectName("playButton")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.playButton)
        self.stopButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralWidget)

        self.stopButton.setText("stop")
        icon3 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon3.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("images/control-stop-square.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.stopButton.setIcon(icon3)
        self.stopButton.setObjectName("stopButton")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.stopButton)
        self.viewButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralWidget)

        self.viewButton.setText("view")
        icon5 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon5.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("images/application-image.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.viewButton.setIcon(icon5)
        self.viewButton.setCheckable(True)
        self.viewButton.setObjectName("viewButton")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.viewButton)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_5)
        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.menuBar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menuBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 484, 22))
        self.menuBar.setObjectName("menuBar")
        self.menuFIle = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menuBar)
        self.menuFIle.setObjectName("menuFIle")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menuBar)
        self.statusBar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusBar.setObjectName("statusBar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusBar)
        self.open_file_action = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.open_file_action.setObjectName("open_file_action")
        self.menuFIle.addAction(self.open_file_action)
        self.menuBar.addAction(self.menuFIle.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Failamp"))
        self.currentTimeLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0:00"))
        self.totalTimeLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0:00"))
        self.menuFIle.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "FIle"))
        self.open_file_action.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open file..."))
        

def hhmmss(ms):
    h, r = divmod(ms, 36000)
    m, r = divmod(r, 60000)
    s, _ = divmod(r, 1000)
    return ("%d:%02d:%02d" % (h,m,s)) if h else ("%d:%02d" % (m,s))


class ViewerWindow(QMainWindow):
    state = pyqtSignal(bool)

    def closeEvent(self, e):
        self.state.emit(False)


class PlaylistModel(QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self, playlist, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PlaylistModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.playlist = playlist

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            media = self.playlist.media(index.row())
            return media.canonicalUrl().fileName()

    def rowCount(self, index):
        return self.playlist.mediaCount()


class ThreadOpenCV(QThread):
    changePixmap = pyqtSignal(QImage)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):                                # +++ parent
        super().__init__()
        self.width = parent.width()                                 # +++
        self.height = parent.height()                               # +++

    def run(self):
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)  
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 24)
       
        while True:
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            if ret:
                frame_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                frame_expanded = np.expand_dims(frame_rgb, axis=0)  
                rgbImage = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

                h, w, ch = rgbImage.shape
                bytesPerLine = ch * w
                convertToQtFormat = QImage(
                    rgbImage.data, w, h, bytesPerLine, QImage.Format_RGB888)
                    
#                p = convertToQtFormat.scaled(640, 480, Qt.KeepAspectRatio) 
# +++
                p = convertToQtFormat.scaled(self.width, self.height, Qt.KeepAspectRatio) # +++
# ------------------------------------------>^^^^^^^^^^<>^^^^^^^^^^^<----
                
                self.changePixmap.emit(p)

                if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
                    break
            
            self.msleep(20)                     
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            

class WidgetForCv2(QtWidgets.QMainWindow,):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.resize(444, 350)                                                   # +++
        
        self.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()  
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.setWindowOpacity(0.6) 
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint) 
        
#        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(640, 480))

        self.label_video = QLabel(self, alignment = Qt.AlignCenter)             # +++
        self.label_video.setMinimumSize(QSize(426, 240))                        # +++
      
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.label_video)

        self.thread = ThreadOpenCV(self)                                       # + self
# -------------------------------> ^^^^ <----------------------------------------------
        
        self.thread.changePixmap.connect(self.setImage)
        
        
    def setImage(self, image):
        self.label_video.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(image))
        
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.thread.width = self.width()
        self.thread.height = self.height()
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^         


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.player = QMediaPlayer()

        self.player.error.connect(self.erroralert)
        self.player.play()

        # Настроить плейлист.
        self.playlist = QMediaPlaylist()
        self.player.setPlaylist(self.playlist)

        # Добавить просмотрщик для воспроизведения видео, отдельное плавающее окно
        self.viewer = ViewerWindow(self)
        self.viewer.setWindowFlags(self.viewer.windowFlags() | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.viewer.setMinimumSize(QSize(1920 ,1080))
        self.viewer.setWindowOpacity(0.6)             

        videoWidget = QVideoWidget()
        self.viewer.setCentralWidget(videoWidget)
        self.player.setVideoOutput(videoWidget)

        self.playButton.pressed.connect(self.player.play)
        self.stopButton.pressed.connect(self.player.stop)
      
        self.viewButton.toggled.connect(self.toggle_viewer)
        self.viewer.state.connect(self.viewButton.setChecked)

        self.model = PlaylistModel(self.playlist)
        self.playlistView.setModel(self.model)
        self.playlist.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.playlist_position_changed)
        selection_model = self.playlistView.selectionModel()
        selection_model.selectionChanged.connect(self.playlist_selection_changed)

        self.player.durationChanged.connect(self.update_duration)
        self.player.positionChanged.connect(self.update_position)
        self.timeSlider.valueChanged.connect(self.player.setPosition)

        self.open_file_action.triggered.connect(self.open_file)

        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        
        self.widgetForCv2 = WidgetForCv2()

    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        if e.mimeData().hasUrls():
            e.acceptProposedAction()

    def dropEvent(self, e):
        for url in e.mimeData().urls():
            self.playlist.addMedia(
                QMediaContent(url)
            )
        self.model.layoutChanged.emit()

        # Если не играет, ищу сначала из недавно добавленных + играть.
        if self.player.state() != QMediaPlayer.PlayingState:
            i = self.playlist.mediaCount() - len(e.mimeData().urls())
            self.playlist.setCurrentIndex(i)
            self.player.play()

    def open_file(self):
        path, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self, 
            "Open file", 
            "", 
            "mp4 Video (*.mp4);;mp3 Audio (*.mp3);;Movie files (*.mov);;avi Video (*.avi)")

        if path:
            self.playlist.addMedia(
                QMediaContent(
                    QUrl.fromLocalFile(path)
                )
            )

        self.model.layoutChanged.emit()

    def update_duration(self, mc):
        self.timeSlider.setMaximum(self.player.duration())
        duration = self.player.duration()

        if duration >= 0:
            self.totalTimeLabel.setText(hhmmss(duration))

    def update_position(self, *args):
        position = self.player.position()
        if position >= 0:
            self.currentTimeLabel.setText(hhmmss(position))

        self.timeSlider.blockSignals(True)
        self.timeSlider.setValue(position)
        self.timeSlider.blockSignals(False)

    def playlist_selection_changed(self, ix):
        # Мы получаем QItemSelection от selectionChanged.
        i = ix.indexes()[0].row()
        self.playlist.setCurrentIndex(i)

    def playlist_position_changed(self, i):
        if i > -1:
            ix = self.model.index(i)
            self.playlistView.setCurrentIndex(ix)

    def toggle_viewer(self, state):
        if state:
            if self.player.state():        
                self.viewer.show()
            else:                          
                self.widgetForCv2.thread.start()                  
                QTimer.singleShot(300, self.widgetForCv2.show)           
        else:
            self.viewer.hide()
            self.widgetForCv2.hide()                         

    def erroralert(self, *args):
        print(args)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName("Failamp")
    app.setStyle("Fusion")

    palette = QPalette()
    palette.setColor(QPalette.Window, QColor(53, 53, 53))
    palette.setColor(QPalette.WindowText, Qt.white)
    palette.setColor(QPalette.Base, QColor(25, 25, 25))
    palette.setColor(QPalette.AlternateBase, QColor(53, 53, 53))
    palette.setColor(QPalette.ToolTipBase, Qt.white)
    palette.setColor(QPalette.ToolTipText, Qt.white)
    palette.setColor(QPalette.Text, Qt.white)
    palette.setColor(QPalette.Button, QColor(53, 53, 53))
    palette.setColor(QPalette.ButtonText, Qt.white)
    palette.setColor(QPalette.BrightText, Qt.red)
    palette.setColor(QPalette.Link, QColor(42, 130, 218))
    palette.setColor(QPalette.Highlight, QColor(42, 130, 218))
    palette.setColor(QPalette.HighlightedText, Qt.black)
    app.setPalette(palette)
    app.setStyleSheet(
        "QToolTip { color: #ffffff; background-color: #2a82da; border: 1px solid white; }")

    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]